# Setting .NET6 ASP.NET controller in a nuget package as AllowAnonymous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I use a nuget package to process markdown files. The package uses a middleware component which loads the markdown file from incoming url and pass it as data to markdown controller by overwriting the context.Request.Path.

When such a mark down file is the first url for a user, it triggers a redirection to Azure AD login. When the user returns from Azure AD, information about the markdown file is lost.

The markdown files does not need to be protected by user login. If I can set the Markdown controller in the nuget package to AllowAnonymous, I assume the problem will be solved.

Is it possible to change the attributes for a controller in a Nuget package? Do other options exist?

Thanks in advance

Kind regards
Soeren

Comment: Can't you override it?

Comment: Not that I know of. I have downloaded the source and set AllowAnonymous for the controller. That fixed the problem, but more elegant solutions probably exist.